# Trying a geometric proof of "Interior of a convex set is convex"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I needed to prove that the interior of a convex set is convex in a Normed Linear space.

I tried a proof using the geometrical and intuitive ideas... I need someone to verify and list out the mistakes, if there are any...

##### Theorem

Interior of a convex set S, is convex

##### Proof:-

If the interior of S contains no element or only one element then the proof is obvious.

Suppose $x,y \in S^o$, then there exists $r_1, r_2$ respectively such that,
$B(x,r_1), B(y,r_2) \subseteq S^o$.
Let $2r=$ min{$r_1,r_2$}

**To prove: $(1-t)x+ty \in S^o$, $t \in (0,1)$**

Let $z=(1-t)x+ty$

Claim: $||z-w||<(1-t)r \implies w \in S$

Fix a point in $B(y,(1-t)r)$, say $y_0$

Let $x_0=\frac{w-ty_0}{1-t}$

Now $w=(1-t)x_0+ty_0$

$$||x-x_0||=\frac{||(1-t)x - w+ty_0||}{1-t}$$
$$=\frac{||(1-t)x+ty -w -ty+ty_0||}{1-t}$$
$$\frac{||z-w + t(y_0-y)||}{1-t} \leq \frac{||z-w||+t||y-y_0||}{1-t}$$
$$< \frac{(1-t)r+t(1-t)r}{1-t} < r+tr < 2r$$

So given any $z$ in the line segment connecting $x,y$.
I shown that the $B_1=B(z,(1-t)r) \subseteq S$ by the following argument

Let $w \in B_1$, then I shown that $w$ is a point in the line connecting $x_0,y_0 \in S$, since $S$ is convex, $w \in S$

this means $B_1 \subseteq S$, which implies $z$ is an interior point of S and hence $z \in S^o$, which completes the proof.

I used my geometric ideas and intuitions to write this proof... is this proof correct? or are there any mistakes, If correct and it needs any improvements kindly tell, If wrong, what's wrong and how to rectify it... TIA

Comment: You can even prove that $B( (1-t)x+ty, \ (1-t)r_1 + t r_2) \subset S$.